# update panel does not working for views

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

i am using updatepanel for a linkbutton so that it doesnot refresh the whole page . on click of that linkbutton i need to set an active view in a multiview control which is working fine without updatepanel. 
but when i use updatepanel it doesnoot work. can you help me how to do this

updatepanel code

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="changephoto" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" OnClick="changephoto_Click">Change Photo</asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="changephoto" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on click event

```
               Protected Sub changephoto_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MultiView_Updates.SetActiveView(View_ChangePhoto)
    'bindprofileimage()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the multiview inside the updatepanel.....

Comment: but i have to use updatepanel in other areas inside multiview too. is this possible to use more updatepanel inside one updatepanel

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/16/112525.aspx    Parent Update Panel refreshes all the contents including Child Update Panel's contents even if the Child Update Panel's update mode is set to Conditional.                                             
Child Update Panel refreshes only its contents and doesn't refresh that of the Parent Update Panel unless, the update mode for the parent update panel is not set to Conditional

Answer (score 1):

If you want set view on click of the linkbutton which is placed inside the update panel, then your Multiview must also be present inside the update panel. Otherwise, the control will not be refreshed.

UpdatePanel controls work by specifying regions of a page that can be updated without refreshing the whole page. An asynchronous postback behaves like a regular postback in that the resulting server page executes the complete page and control life cycle. **However, with an asynchronous postback, page updates are limited to regions of the page that are enclosed in UpdatePanel controls and that are marked to be updated.** The server sends HTML markup for only the affected elements to the browser.

[Using Nested UpdatePanel Controls](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ViewSample.aspx?sref=UpdatePanelTechnologyOverview1#UpdatePanelNestedCS.aspx)

UpdatePanel controls can be nested. If the parent panel is refreshed, all nested panels are refreshed also.

The following example shows markup that defines an UpdatePanel control inside another UpdatePanel control. A button in the parent panel triggers an update of the content in both the parent and the child panel. The button in the child panel triggers an update of only the child panel.